# How to use multiple OK Buttons in an Adobe-JS Custom Dialog Box?

Tags: javascript, pdf, dialog, livecycle-designer

I'm making a custom dialog box with Adobe Livecycle Designer ES2 and I can't find out how or even if it's possible to get two *type:"ok"*-Elements in there doing different things.

I want to have one regular OK-Button at the bottom and I want to have a hyperlink to a website on the top.

That already prevents me of being able to use "`ok_cancel`" et cetera, because as far as I know those buttons aren't separable in the layout.
I don't know how to make the event-handler for the button where I would launch the URL or if it's even possible to handle the click event of "ok"-Elements outside of "commit".
Also I don't understand how the "commit" function chooses its ok-button, because in another Dialog Box of mine it's triggered by the lower OK-Button which is on the bottom of the code unlike in this case where the upper button triggers the "commit" function.

Here's my code to make it clearer - I don't want the "link" element to trigger "commit" but the "okbo" element. And I want to make a new function for the `clickEvent` of "link".

```
var dialogBox =
{
    description:
    {
        elements:
        [{  
            type: "static_text",
            name: "Text about the link",
        },
        {
            type: "ok",
            item_id: "link",
            ok_name: "Go to Link",
        },
        {
            type: "static_text",
            name: "Some more Information",
        },
        {
            type: "ok",
            item_id: "okbo"
        }]
    },
    commit: function(dialog)
    {
        app.alert("This is triggered by the OK-Button with the ID 'link' \n and I don't know why!");
    }
};
app.execDialog(dialogBox);
```

If it's impossible to work with different "ok"-Elements in one Dialog I'm open for suggestions on how to get a Hyperlink in my Dialog in a different way!

This is my very first StackOverflow question so please don't kill me :P ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See updated code and my comments bellow. For more details about Dialog and execDialog function see [here](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/AcroJS.pdf).

Some of the controls are not documented like:

```
•   link_text: a hyper link control
•   mclv: a multi-column list view (or grid)
•   slider: a slider 
•   ok_help, ok_cancel_help, ok_other_help, ok_other_cancel_help controls
•   separator: draw a line horizontal or vertical with optional caption
•   Heading and Title fonts about 10pt and 12pt respectively
•   margin_width, margin_height properties for the view control
•   back_color, gradient_direction, gradient_type for the view control
•   A Dialog.setForeColorRed() method
•   A Dialog.visible() method to show/hide controls
```

See for more details from this [source](http://adobelivecycledesignercookbookbybr001.blogspot.ca/2013_10_01_archive.html)

```
var dialogBox =
    {
        description:
        {
            elements:
            [{      
                name: "Link to google",         
                type: "link_text",  // add a hyperlink  
                item_id: "lnk1",
                alignment: "align_center",      
            },        
            {  
                type: "static_text",
                name: "Text about the link",
            },
            {
                type: "button",  // add a custom button
                item_id: "link",
                name: "Go to Link",
                alignment: "align_center",
            },
            {
                type: "static_text",
                name: "Some more Information",
            },
            {
                type: "ok",
                item_id: "okbo"
            }]
        },
            commit: function(dialog)
            {
                app.alert("okbo!"); //executed only for first ok type
            },

            "link": function () // handler of the custom component by id name
            { 
                xfa.host.gotoURL("http://www.yahoo.com");
            },

            "lnk1": function () 
            { 
                xfa.host.gotoURL("http://www.google.com");
            }

    };
    app.execDialog(dialogBox);
```

Comment: I did read the scripting reference before at Page 98 where I thought the description of `"type"` lists ALL possible types, because it says "it MUST be one of the following" but `"link_text"` isn't in the list. I noticed the same problem with `"font"` in the description it doesn't say `"title"` even though it exists... Is there any document that truly lists ALL the possible types???

Comment: You are right some of the controls are not documented like:

• link_text: a hyper link control
• mclv: a multi-column list view (or grid)
• slider: a slider but I have not got this to return a value.



See for more details here: http://adobelivecycledesignercookbookbybr001.blogspot.ca/2013_10_01_archive.html

Comment: Alright, thanks you so much :)
I've seen this website before, but I never read it carefully - it has much useful information!